# Deploying a complete website to AWS with cloudformation

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have a serverless application with the following components:
5 lambda functions
1 API that integrates with lambdas
1 static website that uses the API to access lambdas with bunch of js html and css files
1 dynamoDB table that is being used by lambdas

I have a cloudformation template that deploys lambdas ,API and dynamoDB table , and its outputs gives the API URL.

My question is what is the best strategy to deploy the static part of the application ,(html , css ,js files) ?I like to host the static content on S3. How can i get the API url from the stack and paste it in my client javascript file and deploy it on a given s3? Is it possible to deploy the whole application with one fat cloudformation template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your application is built, I'm not sure you could deploy it using only cloudformation. A good strategy would be to use the s3 cli to copy the files to the s3 bucket after the cloudformation template has been deployed.

As for getting the API url, to make things easier on yourself, I would suggest creating a DNS record so that you know what it is ahead of time.

You could also use the aws cli to describe the stack after the template has been deployed to retrieve the outputed url.